# rewrite rules on EC2 server conundrum

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

I'm new to the RewriteEngine on Apache, and want to make some SEO friendly urls. I'm sending data to the server in the url i.e. user.php?id=37&activ=2 etc.

I have changed my .htaccess file to include the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id=([0-9]+)$ user.php?id=$1&activ=2
```

now that's all working fine i.e. I can navigate to the appropriate page by typing:

root.com/id=35

and getting the correct page. However when I click an internal link on the site to get the same page I get the url as the old user.php?id=35&activ=2 etc.

how can I make it so that the internal links will show up 'rewritten' and SEO friendly?

Answer (score 0):

The rule:

```
RewriteRule ^id=([0-9]+)$ user.php?id=$1&activ=2
```

Takes an incoming request URI `/id=123` and rewrites it internally to `/user.php?id=123&activ=2`, just like you wanted. **That is all it does**. It won't magically change dynamic content so that links inside `<a>` hrefs get transformed into some new pattern, it won't magically change the content in browsers' location bars. It only does a single thing and that is internally rewrite one URI to another.

You need to change all of you content so that the links no longer look like `/user.php?id=123&activ=2`. There is absolutely nothing mod_rewrite can do in this regard. Unless you change this, people will still be able to hover over your links and see the old URL.

If you need to change external links from one form to the other, then you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /user\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&activ=2
RewriteRule ^ /id=%2? [L,R=301]
```

This externally redirects the URI with the query string to the one without.

Comment: Thanks Jon - that's exactly what I'd like to do - I want to keep my internal links the same, but I want to change the url that the user sees externally so that they will not need to see all the ?id=37 etc.